# Hadith about Nisab corresponding to Yearly Living Cost

Tags: reference-request, zakat, nisab

In the book titled "Contemporary Zakat" by Mahmoud Abu-Saud, he quotes a Hadith which I'm rephrasing here: "The Prophet Muhammad (SAW) order a Zakat Collector by the name of Abu Hathama to take whatever is beyond the living cost."

From this Abu Saud validates the idea that the Nisab corresponds to the average family yearly living cost.

Where can I find this Hadith? I need the reference. If someone has access to his book, please verify if this Hadith is authentic.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE.As you've already quoted the book and it's author can't you add the quote and if possible a link. Doesn't the author reveal his source?

Comment: Walaikumussalam. I don't have the book. I read this in a paper that itself quoted the author.

Comment: But was the author quoted in his own words or as a description as you've done?

Comment: as a description, not in his own words

Comment: I wonder if this is heavily paraphrased. e.g. there is a [hadith](https://shamela.ws/book/10490/9556#p1) about Abu Hathama being sent to assess the 'ushr due on the produce of an orchard. He estimated and exempted an amount that would be used for feeding the owner's family and wasted by wind etc. and the Prophet ﷺ approved of it.

Comment: We cannot conclude from this that the nisab is the living cost of the average family since he meant to estimate the 'ushr and not just any amount equalling the living cost of the average family.